# Python Selenium - How to click element that is not a button

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium in python and trying to click an element that is not a button class. I'm using Google Chrome as my browser/web driver

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/ep9k/Desktop/SeleniumTest/drivers/chromedriver")

driver.get('http://tax.watgov.org/WataugaNC/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address')
driver.find_element_by_name('btAgree').click()             #clicks 'Agree' button to agree to site's terms                                            

driver.find_element_by_name('inpNumber').send_keys('190')
driver.find_element_by_name('inpStreet').send_keys('ELI HARTLEY')
driver.find_element_by_name('btSearch').click()
```

This takes me to this page: 
[image]

I can parse the results HTML (with Beautiful Soup for example), but I want to Click on them. If I inspect the first row of elements, I see this is kept in a div element, with a style of "margin-left:3px;".

But this is not a button element, so the normal click() function does not work. Is there a way to click on this? 
For example, If I click on the first row of results, I am taken to this page with more information (which is what I really want):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element doesn't need to be a button to be clickable.

after I ran your code, I've added:

```py
results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('SearchResults')
first_result = results[0]
first_result.click()
```

And it worked perfectly fine for me.

Most probably you tried to click on some different element and that's why it didn't work

EDIT:
Just to be more precise, most probably you tried to click on a div element inside `<tr>` tag.
while the `<tr>` tag contains `javascript:selectSearchRow('../Datalets/Datalet.aspx?sIndex=1&idx=1')` so your script should click this tag not `<div>`

Comment: This works, thanks!  

One more question. How did you know to use the class name 'SearchResults'?  When I look at the page source it is not clear to me how you chose this instead of the individual <div> tags for each result

Comment: @ErichPurpur I just started inspecting from the whole table and going to table children tags then I noticed that `<tr>` tag contains `onclick` attribute so I knew that this element should be clickable, then I noticed that rows with results contain that class.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the first row with xpath - see below.
Assuming you want to parse each of the results(parcels) after that, make use of the navigation buttons; this is a structure you could use:

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='searchResults']")
table[0].click()

#  Extract the total number of parcels from string e.g. "1 of 24"
string=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='DTLNavigator$txtFromTo']").get_attribute('value')
#  split string in separate words; last word i.e. [-1] is the total number of parcels e.g. "24"
total_parcels=string.split(' ')[-1]

for record in range(int(total_parcels)):
    # >>> parse record here <<<
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='DTLNavigator$imageNext']").click()
    time.sleep(0.5) # be considerate to your source and don't load their server with numerous quick requests
```

Answer (score 1):

induce `WebDriverWait` and following `css` selector to click table item.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/ep9k/Desktop/SeleniumTest/drivers/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://tax.watgov.org/WataugaNC/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"btAgree"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"inpNumber"))).send_keys('190')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"inpStreet"))).send_keys('ELI HARTLEY')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"btSearch"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"tr.SearchResults"))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]